# Handling listener calls from row in CursorLoader

Tags: android, listener, android-cursorloader

I have custom `CursorListener`, rows contain various items (buttons/switches etc.) I want to handle callbacks from row within the `CursorLoader`. Can I set listener in the newView e.g.

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
MyView view = (MyView) LayoutInflater.from(
                parent.getContext())
                      .inflate(R.layout.row_courses_default, parent, false);

     view.setMyViewListener(this);

return view;
}
```

Is it ok to do it like that? I'm worried that I'm setting reference to `this` but never set it to `null`.

**edit**
In the `setMyListener` I'm setting the reference as `WeakReference<MyViewListener>`.